# how to set value from picker to customized cell textfield of particular section?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row==1)
        {

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"custom1TableViewCell";

            custom1TableViewCell *cell2 = (custom1TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell2 == nil)
            {

                cell2 = [[ custom1TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


            }


            NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
            cell2.language.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            //for picker


            [cell2.sellanguage setInputView:pickerview];
            cell2.sellanguage.text = selectedLanguage;



            return cell2;
        }


        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customTableViewCell";

        customTableViewCell *cell = (customTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



        if (cell == nil)
        {

            cell = [[customTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }


        NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        cell.soundfx.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        return cell;

    }
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

    [pickerview selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"%@",[languages objectAtIndex:row]);

    selectedLanguage= [languages objectAtIndex:row];


    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: it works but...i want to set value to textfield using customised cell variable inside did select row method of a picker

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // now you can use cell.textLabel.text
    //For Example
    self.textfield.text = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: hi sir, actually i want to set value to customised cell textfield so i dont know how to set value inside picker method(didselectrow)...refer above above...thanks in advance...